# Looping the listing files in UNIX

Tags: loops, unix

I given command

```
ls -lrt
```

and the listed files and directories are

```
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root    4096 Feb  2  2014 abc
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root    4096 Feb  2  2014 cde
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root    4096 Feb  2  20014 efg
-rwxr-xr-x   4 root root    4096 Feb  2  20014 aaa.txt
```

now I want to find whether the listed output files are directory or not by using loop.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean, by using a loop?

Comment: I want to run all files in a for loop or while loop to test the file is directory or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for l in `ls -l|awk '{print $9}'`
do
    p=`file $l`
echo $p
done
```

Other option would be to check the first option in permissions. "d" directory. "-" file

EDIT :

```
for l in `ls -l|grep -v total |awk '{print $1}'|cut -b1`
do
if [ $l == "-" ]
then
    echo "File"
else
if [ $l == "d" ]
then
    echo "Directory"
fi
fi
done
```

Comment: This won't work if any of the filenames contains whitespace or weird characters ls(1) will convert into question marks, for example U+007F (DELETE) or non-UTF-8 characters.

Comment: What abut the second script ?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an X/Y problem, where you're asking for X but actually want Y.

Are you trying to get a list of all the directories?  Use the `find` command.

```
find . -type d
```

Comment: i can list the directories by using `ls -ld` too. but i want to check in a loop(for or while).I want run all files in a loop to check it is a directory or not

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this? In bash:

> ls | while read f; do test -d "$f" && echo $f is a directory || echo $f is not a directory; done

This lists all the files in the current directory and checks if every file is a directory or not. To test for directories in subdirectories too, replace the initial "ls" with "find".